# How to set query in URL and how to find Objects by an array of Strings in mongoose?

Tags: express, url, mongoose

If I have this Schema...

```
maid = {
    services: [{
        type: String,
        enum: ["cleaning", "cooking", "baby sitting"]
    }]
}
```

1. How would I write query in URL to find all maids having services "cleaning" and "cooking" only.

Example: "http://company/maids?services=cleaning,cooking" or in some other way.

2. How to find all maids from database with required services?
   Example:

```
Maid.find({
    services: {
        $all:req.query.services
    }
})
```

or

```
Maid.find(req.query);
```

Please suggest some good ways to do the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use should use `http://company/maids?services=cleaning,cooking`
2. Use could use this $all in mongodb like `Maid.find({services:{$all: req.query.services.split(',')}})`

*ps: Use have to validate the query before search*